# How to update one message if there are two messages in same div in primefaces on updating that div

Tags: primefaces

There are two messages given in the div and if we update that div both the messages get updated then how to update that single messages in primefaces
below you can find what i've tried so far

```
 <p:confirmDialog id="deleteDlg" message="Are you sure, you want to delete ?" header="Delete" widgetVar="deleteWidget" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" draggable="true"> 
<p:commandButton value="Yes" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();" id="yes" actionListener="#{searchBean.onDelete}" update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg terminalSearchForm @(.error)">    </p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton value="No" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();" update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg"/> 
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: please post some code (what you have done so far)

Comment: <p:confirmDialog id="deleteDlg"
    message="Are you sure, you want to delete ?" header="Delete"
    widgetVar="deleteWidget" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true"
    draggable="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();" id="yes"
     actionListener="#{searchBean.onDelete}"
     update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg terminalSearchForm @(.error)">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="No" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();"
        update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg"/>
   </p:confirmDialog>

Comment: in dialog there is a message and in a form there is another message...on clicking yes commandbutton it update bboth the message

Comment: Edit your question...and format your code. Read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Answer: Don't update the div but the single message(s)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to update something in your page think like you have a tree the deep you want to update the more you want to dig

It's look like this

```
 <p:someElement id="id1" ....>
  <p:someElement  id="idS1" ....   update=":id1:idS1"   />
  <p:someElement  id="idS2" .... />
 </p:someElement
```

In my example if i want to update `idS1 + idS2` i will say `update=":id1"`
 and of corse it will update `id1` informations

You can read this post [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes) am sure it will help

About your example

```
 <p:confirmDialog id="deleteDlg" message="Are you sure, you want to delete ?" header="Delete" widgetVar="deleteWidget" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" draggable="true"> 
  <p:commandButton id="btn1" value="Yes" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();" id="yes" actionListener="#{searchBean.onDelete}" update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg terminalSearchForm @(.error)">    </p:commandButton>
  <p:commandButton id="btn2" value="No" oncomplete="PF('deleteWidget').hide();" update=":terminalSearchForm:deleteDlg:btn2"/> 
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

Feel free to ask for more informations